# Как организовать журналирование insert / update / delete для нескольких таблиц?

Tags: mysql, триггер

Используется
    MySQL - 5.7 - х64

Имеется несколько  таблиц с приблизительно следующим кол. и типам полей. 
Количество полей и типов полей у разных таблиц разное.

Примерный состав таблиц:

- pol_1 — DATE,
- pol_2 — ENUM,
- pol_3 — TEXT,
- pol_4 — DATE,
- pol_5 — TEXT,
- pol_6 — DATE,
- pol_7 — TEXT,
- pol_8 — INT,
- pol_9 — INT,
- pol_10 — TEXT,
- pol_11 — TEXT,
- pol_12 — LONGTEXT,
- pol_13 — INT,
- pol_14 — INT,
- pol_15 — INT,
- pol_16 — INT,
- pol_17 — INT,
- pol_18 — TEXT,
- pol_19 — TEXT.

Т.е. по сути в каждой таблице используются следующие типы полей:

- `DATE`
- `ENUM`
- `TEXT`
- `INT`
- `LONGTEXT`

Требуется отследить события  `insert` / `update` / `delete` для каждой записи каждого поля.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что по сути, необходимо для каждого типа поля сделать  отдельный журнал, куда будут стекаться данные из разных таблиц? См. скрин.

**ВОПРОС**

1. Как правильно организовать журналирование?
2. Как будет выглядеть пример триггера(ов) для такой задачи?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете сделать одну таблицу и записывать туда (таблица-поле-старое-новое-время). Можете просто в каждую таблицу ввести поле validity, которое true, если поле валидно, и false, если нет, а вместо изменений создавать новую запись, а старую помечать невалидной. Можете использовать и иные варианты журналирования.

Comment: @Akina "Можете сделать одну таблицу и записывать туда (таблица-поле-старое-новое-время)." - старое-новое-время - вы имеете ввиду так для каждого поля? Старый-новый - текст?

Comment: А почему нет? ведь любой тип можно обратимо сериализовать в текстовый... а исходный тип определяется свойствами поля таблицы.

Comment: @Akina Кажется, начал понимать... Думаю, лучше было бы решение журнала с составом полей: id, датавремя, таблица, поле, новое значение. Не могли бы показать как такой триггера ссериализацией может выглядеть?.. или где почитать? Что-то при первоначальном поиске ничего под руку не попалось..

Comment: А зачем id? имхо лишнее поле.

Comment: @Akina Кстати.. id... "Можете сделать одну таблицу" - вы имеете ввиду таблицу журнала? Наверное уточню, предыдущее своё сообщение. Состав полей журнала: idЖурнал, idЗаписиТаблицы, ДатаВремя, Таблица, Поле, Новое значение..  Если, какие-то мои решения нелогичны, то прошу скорректировать исходя из своего опыта, т.к. я пока осваиваю это направление...

Comment: idЖурнал опять же - лишнее. Толку от него - ноль. У тебя же есть поле Таблица.

Comment: @Akina Понял.. Всё таки, если есть возможность, пример триггера с сериализацией подскажете?.

Comment: Да в чём проблема? одно поле, базовый тип... обычный CAST...